# Guest accounts dont read the content of Azure AD

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-active-directory

I have two tenants, A and B, and B tenant has guest users from A tenant. They use Power BI Service, everything works apart from:

everywhere with the input field where you put users name, such as adding users to a workspace, or when adding permissions to an app, the name/account suggestions don't come up, which means no users can be added. Even copy and pasting the UPN doesnt work, it's like the guest account is not reading the AAD of the tenant.
With "home" account in this tenant, everything works - if i start typing a user name, suggestions come up.
But doing the same with the guest account in this tenant, it's like the guest account doesnt have access to AAD.

This is the same problem, without solution
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Issues/Adding-Users-to-a-Workspace-does-not-work/idi-p/2477951

Any advice will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users with their type set to "Guest" cannot enumerate users in the tenant.
If you change their type to "Member", they should be able to then.

Note this is a separate thing from invited/local accounts.
Invited users just get the "Guest" type by default.
But it can be changed.

Comment: Many thanks juunas. These guest accounts are also unable to read the AAD in portal.azure.com - the portal page opens, but when clicking on Azure Active Directory, the page display "You dont have access" - is this by design?

Comment: Yes, by default users with type Guest have more restricted access. You can check from here in the docs for info on guest vs member permissions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#compare-member-and-guest-default-permissions